# How to post a link into Stack Exchange chat so that its details get shown?

Tags: support, chat, hyperlinks, onebox

When other people post a link to their question in Stack Exchange chat, they get a rich link with wonderful decorations, tags, description, excerpt, and large fonts:

[image: Stack chat]

When I try to do the same, I just paste the link to my question, but all I get is this pitiful link:

[image: no rich text]

Why is this?

Comment: Put the link by itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get your SE link to "onebox" you must post it on its own line, as its own message.

For your example your first line would be

> i18n astonishing problem:

Send that and then as your second line put the link to your question:

> `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797758`